# Monospace font that supports both English and Japanese

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for a monospaced font that supports both English and Japanese. All characters should be the same width (since it's monospace).

I haven't found anything that works from looking on the internet. Google has created a font called Noto Mono, a monospace version of their font family Noto, which is supposed to support all languages. However, the English and Japanese characters are different widths here too.

Update: Migu 2M is closer, with English letters exactly 50% of Japanese.

Update 2: Here's a square, monospace, English font that reads well: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LqGQ.jpg)

Comment: The problem is that european letters have a distunctly nonsquare aspect ratio. Its really hard to find any font that would make for square letters.

Comment: @joojaa But that's quite easy to get around. Make the letters something like 3:2 to work with English, and keep Japanese square. Japanese gets more space between rows, but that's fine.

Comment: Yes but then the european letters are bigger. Realistically Kanji characters need more space to be readable making the european characters very large. Anyway nothing stops you from instructing your  applicatoon to let european characters have more space between them (most systems can assign tracking). Just that you didnt specify you wanted it the other way around.

Comment: @joojaa "nothing stops you from instructing your applicatoon..." Would that be possible in css/javascript? I've never heard of anything like it.

Comment: @joojaa I know I can do it (with some effort) by drawing characters pixel by pixel, but then things like copying text don't work.

Comment: you can adjust tracking with css **letter-spacing** property. All you need then to do is mark the areas that are in japanese and not (which shouldnt be hard)

Comment: [Source Han Code JP](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-code-jp) has a 2:3 width ratio of latin and japanese characters.

Answer (score 4):

I think something like IBM Plex could be what you are looking for, since it was specifically designed to support globalization and localization:

According to the [website for IBM Plex font](https://www.ibm.com/plex/) (which I think is probably a little bit more animated than required):

> IBM Plex™ is our new typeface. It’s global, it’s versatile and it’s
>   distinctly IBM.

And it appears to come in in serif, sans serif, and monospace versions. Just check out the [github repo](https://github.com/IBM/plex) for the font.

Comment: [image](https://imgur.com/a/QYli22Q) Seems like IBM Plex Mono has monospace within English, monospace within Japanese, and a 5:3 ratio between them.

Comment: Oh I hate the 5:3 ratio, why don't they set the ratio to 1:2 (English : Japanese) :(

Comment: Japanese support is still missing according to the [github page](https://github.com/IBM/plex).

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution: Source Han Sans actually has the 1000-width versions. They are hidden under fulwifth substitution, so in an enough OpenType-savvy environment, you just turn the `fwid` feature on and enjoy. Otherwise you may edit it in any font editor to make those forms default for the Unicode points.

fwid off:
[image: fwid off]

fwid on:
[image: fwid on]

Answer (score 0):

Japanese has two characters for each letter in the Hiragana, Katakana and Romaji (Latin) alphabets. One character is "half width" and the other "full width". Kanji characters by contrast are full width. For all characters to be the same width regardless of language you require:

1. Any monospace Japanese font that includes Kanji.
2. Full width Hiragana, Katakana and Romaji character input.

Any monospace Japanese font that includes Kanji will include all the characters you need in both languages to achieve your objective, for example MS Gothic on Windows and macOS will almost certainly have a monospace Japanese font for you to test with. Make sure you input full width characters as your OS will default to half width the most common use.